# in Javascript, is there a way for a polymorphic setter

Tags: javascript, polymorphism, closures, setter

Background: a library object has a property that is intended to be a method but is often mistakenly accessed by programmers as a property ->
e.g., intended interface:

```
this.filter(function(){...});
```

which is often mistakenly used as

```
this.filter=function(){...};
```

which, of course, overrides the method. (ouch).

The first attempt to handle the situation is by changing

```
this.filter = function(implementation) {
              this.format = implementation;
              this.isfilter = true;
              }
```

to

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "filter", {
    get:  function() { return this.format; },
    set:  function(implementation) {
              this.format = implementation;
              this.isfilter = true;
              }
    });
```

which is well and good for the mistaken use case (this.filter=...)
but of course the first (intended case, this.filter(function(){}))
can no longer work.

Is there any way for polymorphism in this case? ie to handle both
situations - a) not blow away extant code, and b) either, 1) handle the assignment OR issue a warning/exception for the mis-use case?
Or is there some closure magic that can accomplish this?

Comment: You can use Object.freeze(this.filter), not an use of polymorphism, but this won't allow users to override it.

Answer (score 0):

This can certainly be done.

By replacing the method with a `get` only property returns a function.

Using an ES2015 class:

```
class Filterable {
    get filter() {
        return (implementation) => {
            this.format = implementation;
            this.isfilter = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the absence of a property setter.

Attempting to assign to this property will fail, and throw an error in strict mode (Always use strict mode!)

Example:

```js
"use strict";

class Filterable {
  get filter() {
    return (implementation) => {
      this.format = implementation;
      this.isfilter = true;
    }
  }
}

const filterable = new Filterable();

filterable.filter(function (){}); // OK

filterable.filter = function () {}; // Error
```

Of course, you don't need an ES2015 class for this, it will work with define property as you've used it.

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "filter", {
    get: function () {
      return function(implementation) {
        this.format = implementation;
        this.isfilter = true;
      };
    }
});
```